# Postgresql slow query in Materialized Views

Tags: sql, postgresql

Create Materialized Views "mviews_price2"

```
id                 - Integer
price             - Integer
price2            - Integer
unit_price        - Integer
location_site_id - Integer  
leave_site_id    - Integer
web              - Boolean
category_id      - Integer
```

Create Index:

```
CREATE INDEX "location_site_id_idx" ON "mviews_price2" ("location_site_id")
CREATE INDEX "leave_site_id_idx" ON "mviews_price2" ("leave_site_id")
CREATE INDEX "web_idx" ON "mviews_price2" ("web")
```

Get Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "mviews_price2"."category_id" FROM "mviews_price2" WHERE ("mviews_price2"."location_site_id" = 1 OR "mviews_price2"."leave_site_id" = 1 OR "mviews_price2"."web" = true)
```

Explain:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=42757.45..42757.82 rows=37 width=4) (actual time=596.252..596.257 rows=37 loops=1)'
Group Key: category_id'
->  Seq Scan on mviews_price2  (cost=0.00..39614.90 rows=1257021 width=4) (actual time=0.038..362.877 rows=1341021 loops=1)'
        Filter: ((location_site_id = 1) OR (leave_site_id = 1) OR web)'
        Rows Removed by Filter: 423439'
Planning time: 0.954 ms'
Execution time: 596.311 ms'
```

In View - 1764460 lines

Questions:

1. Why it does not use Index?
2. Why query very slow?

Answer (score 0):

`OR` is very difficult to optimize.  Try writing the query using `UNION` instead:

```
SELECT "mviews_price2"."category_id"
FROM "mviews_price2"
WHERE "mviews_price2"."location_site_id" = 1
UNION  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
SELECT "mviews_price2"."category_id"
FROM "mviews_price2"
WHERE "mviews_price2"."leave_site_id" = 1
UNION  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
SELECT "mviews_price2"."category_id"
FROM "mviews_price2"
WHERE "mviews_price2"."web" = true;
```

Each subquery should be able to take advantage of one of the indexes.

Note:  This still may not speed the query.  The index on `web` -- in particular -- is one a field with only 2 values (or 3 if it can take on `NULL`).  Unless `web` is very rare, the result will probably still be a full-table scan.

Comment: Would having a single index on all 3 columns help? I am sure it works for AND, wouldn't OR be an easier constraint to achieve?

Comment: @cplusplusrat . . . No.  With `or` only the first key in the index would be used.